# MacBook Pro 2010 won't boot after EFI upgrade

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, efi

I have updated my MacBook Pro (Core i5, early 2010) with system update to new EFI version, and now after startup it just shows the gray screen and doesen't react on keyboard (just plays the boot sound).

I cannot open boot menu (Option key) and cannot boot from other device.
Command+S does not help.
Only thing that it reacts is Command-Option-P-R, but then it still won't boot.

Tech details:
Installed 8 GB memory and 120 GB vertex2 SSD drive

Comment: If it's stuck at the gray screen, read http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17499/what-should-you-do-if-your-os-x-system-fails-to-boot-being-stuck-at-gray-screen.

Comment: Removed vertex2 ssd - mac booted. 

Looks like it's failed, because if I install the ssd to other sata slot mac book does not boot too. Also this drive is invisible with external sata to usb adapter. 

It's good to have a time capsule!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed vertex2 SSD - Mac booted.

Looks like the SSD has failed, because if I install the SSD to other SATA slot, the MacBook does not boot, either. Also, this drive is invisible with external SATA to USB adapter.

It's Good to have a backup solution.